# How to join an edge of fabric.js Path to a circle?

Tags: fabricjs

I found an example for quadratic curve in the fabric.js [website](https://web.archive.org/web/20200723161634/http://fabricjs.com:80/quadratic-curve).

I want to join a fabric.js circle with one of the edges of the quadratic curve. Is there a way to do it. If I group the point representing one of the edges with say a circle, the point gets separated from the path upon moving the circle

**Update after trying out a few things**

There are two elements - One a circle and another a quadratic curve

With hints from the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652000/control-line-points-make-rectangle-follow-line-but-make-bounding-box-adapt-to-n

The following code has been written for testing:

a. User clicks on the circle (so it becomes activeObject). After that, the following function is run:

```
join_obj1 = canvas.getActiveObject(); // The circle in this case

join_obj2 = the first point (p0) of the line

join_obj3 = the third point (p3) of the line

join_obj1.on('moving', function (options) {
    var x=join_obj1.getLeft();
    var y=join_obj1.getTop();
    join_obj3.path[0] = ["M", x, y]; // Sets the path co-ordinates
    join_obj2.top = y;               // Sets the first point co-ordinates
    join_obj2.left = x;              // Sets the first point co-ordinates
// Following will be tried for joining the third point
//        join_obj3.top = y;
//        join_obj3.left = x;

    canvas.renderAll();
    
});
```

The above code is successfully able to join the left edge of the line (the first point and the line's origin) to the circle and it works fine. When I move the circle, the line and the first point move with it. However, I am not sure how to join the right side edge of the line with the circle. join_obj3.path[0] = ["M", x, y] sets the co-ordinates for the left side of the path. However, I am not sure how to set the right side edge of the path to specific values

Comment: Show us what you tried ... some code whoud be nice

Comment: Updated the question with what has been tested

Comment: Hi, sorry ... but can you do a jsFiddle ? I don't really understand but if I'll see it in jsFiddle I'll probably do. It will take like 5-10 minutes if you want to do it.

Comment: I tried getting it to work in jsfiddle, but could not. Here is the link to the non-working code anyway: https://jsfiddle.net/of7s0wqs/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quadratic bézier curves are defined using the 'Q' directive in the `fabric.Path`. The initial 'M' directive sets the first point (65,0). Two co-ordinates follow the 'Q'; the single control point (100,100) and the final point we’re drawing to (300,100).

That means you last point in the Quadratic Bézier Curve is x = 300, y = 100.

So try something like `join_obj3.path[1] = ["Q", 100, 100, x, y];`

[Here](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/svg-curves/quadratic-curve.html) is a nice example of a Quadratic Bézier Curve.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It worked. I am unable to vote the answer up, as I don't have enough reputation